# How do I parse php values in the ionic grid

Tags: php, json, ionic-framework

[This is the response I am getting through my html document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/454tA.png)Guys I want to display values in a table format in ionic. So I am using grid to get the same output. I am facing a lot of problems when it comes to parsing the data from a json response. I have created a json response and want to display the values in a table format. This is my json response.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [{
        "iMISParamCatID": "1",
        "vCatName": "Alerts",
        "iLocID": "1",
        "paramname": "-ve Batches",
        "fValue": "399.00"
    },, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "6",
        "paramname": "Discounts",
        "fValue": "367.48"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "7",
        "paramname": "Discounts",
        "fValue": "530.21"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "1",
        "paramname": "Owners",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "2",
        "paramname": "Owners",
        "fValue": "3869.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "3",
        "paramname": "Owners",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "4",
        "paramname": "Owners",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "5",
        "paramname": "Owners",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "6",
        "paramname": "Owners",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "7",
        "paramname": "Owners",
        "fValue": "343.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "1",
        "paramname": "Staff",
        "fValue": "547.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "2",
        "paramname": "Staff",
        "fValue": "1422.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "3",
        "paramname": "Staff",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "4",
        "paramname": "Staff",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "5",
        "paramname": "Staff",
        "fValue": "1294.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "6",
        "paramname": "Staff",
        "fValue": "175.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "7",
        "paramname": "Staff",
        "fValue": "1227.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "1",
        "paramname": "Margin",
        "fValue": "14.92"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "2",
        "paramname": "Margin",
        "fValue": "19.18"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "3",
        "paramname": "Margin",
        "fValue": "8.87"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "4",
        "paramname": "Margin",
        "fValue": "9.38"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "5",
        "paramname": "Margin",
        "fValue": "17.58"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "6",
        "paramname": "Margin",
        "fValue": "20.65"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "7",
        "paramname": "Margin",
        "fValue": "17.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "1",
        "paramname": "Profit",
        "fValue": "13227.30"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "2",
        "paramname": "Profit",
        "fValue": "91215.79"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "3",
        "paramname": "Profit",
        "fValue": "39471.89"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "4",
        "paramname": "Profit",
        "fValue": "27122.51"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "5",
        "paramname": "Profit",
        "fValue": "18488.92"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "6",
        "paramname": "Profit",
        "fValue": "13984.54"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "2",
        "vCatName": "Sales",
        "iLocID": "7",
        "paramname": "Profit",
        "fValue": "11667.46"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "6",
        "vCatName": "Accounts",
        "iLocID": "1",
        "paramname": "Register",
        "fValue": "69150.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "6",
        "vCatName": "Accounts",
        "iLocID": "2",
        "paramname": "Register",
        "fValue": "-1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "6",
        "vCatName": "Accounts",
        "iLocID": "3",
        "paramname": "Register",
        "fValue": "1.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "6",
        "vCatName": "Accounts",
        "iLocID": "4",
        "paramname": "Register",
        "fValue": "25470.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "6",
        "vCatName": "Accounts",
        "iLocID": "5",
        "paramname": "Register",
        "fValue": "58819.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "6",
        "vCatName": "Accounts",
        "iLocID": "6",
        "paramname": "Register",
        "fValue": "42650.00"
    }, {
        "iMISParamCatID": "6",
        "vCatName": "Accounts",
        "iLocID": "7",
        "paramname": "Register",
        "fValue": "68228.00"
    }]
}
```

This is my html file

```
   <ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        Display Date
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        #1
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col>
        #2
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col>
        #3
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        #4
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        #5
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        #6
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        #7
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        Total
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        Category Name
      </ion-col><br>
    </ion-row>  
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
        Category Params 
          </ion-col>
          <ion-row *ngFor = "let category of data?.data">
          <ion-col>
            {{category.fValue}}
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
  </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

And this is my ts file.

```
export class HomePage {
  posts: any;
  leaddetails: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private http: Http) {
    // window.open("http://google.com",'_system', 'location=yes');
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.post('http://url/foldername/file.php',options) 
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Api Fired",data);
    this.data = data;

       });

}

}
```

I just want the values to be printed below the column names and as seen in my response above i need to print the vCatName and paramsname. I am a beginner in ionic i just need guidance.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: i need to print data in the table/grid. so i need to read the values from the response and print it on the page.

Comment: But you mentioned you are facing problems trying to do that, what are those problems?

Comment: the data when i try printing gives me this error data.json is not a function

Comment: `let leaddetails = data.json();` is your problem. You are trying to call a property as a function.

Comment: i have updated my code now the error i get is this Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: You need to parse the object, `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: added this line       this.data = JSON.parse(this.data);  instead of this.data = data

Comment: getn this error    Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: Ensure you response is valid JSON.

Comment: I have validated my json on jsonlint and it is a valid json

Comment: I have updated my answer and your guidance has helped me achieve this output @Script47. Now I just need to print them in an organised way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class HomePage {
posts: any;
leaddetails: any;

alldata: Observable<any>; //<-- this add first
```

and into your http post;

```
  .subscribe(data => {
  console.log("Api Fired",data);

  this.alldata = data; //<--this add

   });
```

later your html file;

```
 <ion-content>
   <ion-grid>
     <ion-row *ngFor="let item of alldata">
       <ion-col>
        {{item.iMISParamCatID}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col>
        {{item.vCatName}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col>
        {{item.iLocID}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col>
        {{item.paramname}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col>
        {{item.fValue}}
       </ion-col>
     <ion-row>
   <ion-grid>
 <ion-content>
```

Comment: data is no getting displayed

Comment: changed to *ngFor="let item of alldata?.data" worked for me

Comment: if i want to print  a specific value how do i print it? eg: vCatName